# Is there a way that we can mint native coin more in ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, evm, ethereumjs

I mean if i have my own private evm chain. the intial supply for it is, assumingly, 10000 coins. after starting the blockchain can I create more coins for that.
Like minting and burning works for tokens?
Also one another thing, is there a way that we charge gas fee in token at some specific address?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple native assets are not currently availanle in the standard EVM.

See this [discussion](https://x.com/paulrberg/status/1701863355470753990?s=46&t=ENkNXVHfiFNrK4yJomEHgg) I started on Twitter about this topic.